# What is the longest rhymonym?

Tags: word, open-ended

What is the longest pair of words you can find that rhyme and can also be synonyms / used to describe the same phenomenon?

For instance, `spot` and `dot`. The goal is to have the longest total length so this example would be scored as 7. A quick thesaurus check and it can be improved to `spot`+`blot`=8. How high can you score?

(If it may be unclear how the two words are synonyms, please provide an explanation and / or example.)

<sub>I realize this may turn into a competition for the best dictionary, thesaurus, and programming skills but it should be a challenge either way.</sub>

Comment: ["In_________ means _________?  What a country!"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q8mD2hsxrhQ)

Comment: @humn That would be 20 and hints at a possible weak spot in this question.

Comment: From a parallel world: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19197/what-words-sound-like-opposites-but-are-synonyms

Comment: I don't know if a word would be considered a rhyme if it's just a subset of another word. Like sandwich and which or witch.

Comment: @DrXorile I guess [maybe](http://m.rhymer.com/RhymingDictionary/sandwich.html) but it's certainly not as clever that way.

Comment: @DrXorile The very fair Duchess of Sandwich / Was also known as a left-hand witch. / She turned into bread, / And her husband then said, / "which sandwich witch is the witch Sandwich"?

Comment: @JoeZ. These are excellent.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because without defining "word" it turns into an ill-defined, open-ended puzzle (and [open-ended puzzles are off-topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles) as of May 2019)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Answer:**

> Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis and silicosis

This might be a bit iffy but this has a score of **54**

**Not an actual answer below** 
And if you want to get technical:

> [image: Chemical name of Titin] 
> and Protein for a score of **189,826** 
>  Sadly this is one is a near miss 
>  [Full Word](http://www.sarahmcculloch.com/luminary-uprise/2009/longest-word/)

Comment: Funnily enough, I wouldn't have been able to type that answer without that protein

Comment: I want to upvote [your first answer](https://www.google.com/search?q=longest+english+word&oq=longest) but can't until you delete that second answer.

Comment: You could relabel the second answer as a spectacular example of a near miss because one word is an instance of the other, not exactly a synonym.

Comment: You should at least use "Titine", not Protein, then it is in some sense synonym...

Comment: I want to see @JoeZ. do a Limerick with this one...

Comment: @Maxim I didn't think titin rhymed with "...leucine"

Comment: @humn the rules said "What is the longest pair of words... used to describe the same phenomenon?" So I think it works

Comment: also since I couldn't tag @user1717828 in the last comment.

Comment: @EngineerToast There once was a man with scoliosis / Who also contracted silicosis. / But worst of them all, / Was that he did fall / To pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis.

Comment: @JoeZ. That is extremely impressive!

Comment: @humn i see what you're getting at, by phenomena op probably meant a fact or situation. I'll change it, unless op says that it works

Comment: Nice edit recovery. The best of all possible wor(l)ds! (Now safe to upvote, @user1717828. )

Comment: @humn hah! I see what you did there.

Comment: I'd have to side with [Oxford](http://web.archive.org/web/20080913120655/http://www.askoxford.com/asktheexperts/faq/aboutwords/longestword) that the chemical name for Titin isn't really a word but the 54 points is still impressive.

Comment: @EngineerToast Fair enough, I'm happy with 54 as it is

Comment: Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis was invented in 1935 but it seems to have been accepted since then. It irks me a bit that it was invented partially just so it could be the longest word but that doesn't invalidate it. If I don't hear any convincing arguments to the contrary and you can make it more clear that the 189,826 answer is not what's being accepted, I'll accept this an the answer.

Comment: @EngineerToast is that clear enough?

Comment: It works for me. I'll give it a day to ensure nobody has a reason to argue and I'll accept it. Overly awesome job.

Comment: @EngineerToast thanks man! It's always fun to answer a great question

Answer (score 24):

Since I don't think this is substantially worse than what's been suggested, I'll use it as a legitimate answer:

> `friggatriskaidekaphobia` and `paraskevidekatriaphobia`

for a score of **46**.

Comment: Cool, both are shown at this Wikipedia page: [triskaidekaphobia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triskaidekaphobia)

Comment: A man with friggatriskaidekaphobia / also had paraskevidekatriaphobia. / He wondered one Friday / (The 13th 'fore Pi-day), / "Do I also have plain triskaidekaphobia?"

Comment: @JoeZ. I know a friend with triskaidekaphobia. Tell me if I'm wrong, but I believe it is a fear of triangles? I don't know what it means when the prefix "figga" is added...

Comment: @user477343 No, it's fear of the number 13. Adding 'frigga-' makes it the fear of Friday the 13th.

Comment: @nickgard hahah, doing a little bit of research, the phobia of triangles is **trianglephobia** (seriously). Why was that so hard to remember?? Perhaps I just made a mistake on what the phobia actually was about...

Answer (score 11):

Current definite best:

> $36$
>  Counterproductiveness Mischievousness
> - causing trouble (can't pluralise the former with es like the latter for $40$ unfortunately)

Previous definate best:

> $33$:
>  Internationali$\kern2mu\sf\small\rlap{\raise7mu s}\raise-3mu z \kern1mu$ation Globali$\kern2mu\sf\small\rlap{\raise7mu s}\raise-3mu z \kern1mu$ation

Hmm are either of these actually OK?:

> $41$ ($39$ without hyphens):
>  Self-characteri$\kern2mu\sf\small\rlap{\raise7mu s}\raise-3mu z \kern1mu$ation Self-differentiation
>
>  $35$:
>  Recharacteri$\kern2mu\sf\small\rlap{\raise7mu s}\raise-3mu z \kern1mu$ation Redifferentiation

I thought I had

> $34$ with:
>  Intellectuali$\kern2mu\sf\small\rlap{\raise7mu s}\raise-3mu z \kern1mu$ation Rationali$\kern2mu\sf\small\rlap{\raise7mu s}\raise-3mu z \kern1mu$ation, but [Wikipedia disagrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intellectualization).

Comment: I wouldn't count "counterproductiveness" and "mischievousness" because they don't have the same sounds from the stressed syllable onwards. The only thing they have in common is that they end in "ness".

Comment: A little boy of much mischievousness / Was a bastion of counterproductiveness. / His mistress did swear, / To bring him to bear, / On the ramifications of his rambunctiousness.

Comment: @JoeZ. no mention of a perfect rhyme requirement, but I hear you.

Answer (score 7):

This pair of words is worth 26 points:

> Autobiography (13 letters) and self-biography (also 13 letters not including the hyphen)

Comment: Are they synonyms or used to describe the same phenomenon?

Comment: Good rhyme but how are they synonyms?

Comment: @EngineerToast, I've updated it and it fits the rules better.

Comment: I'm writing an autobiography, / Which of course shall include much photography. / Every moment I shoot, / The snap shall be put, / Right here in my own self-biography.

Comment: `own self-biography` is redundant.

Comment: Yes, but sometimes one must distort language for meter.

Comment: @JoeZ., couldn't you just say `Right here in this self-biography.`

Comment: Then "Right" would be stressed, and I prefer not to stress the first syllable of a limerick line.

Comment: @Peanut also, "this self-biography" could be anyone's self-biography. "Own self biography" isn't entirely redundant.

Answer (score 2):

I have another answer.

> **Bathmophobia** and **Climacophobia**.

Definitions:

- > **Bathmophobia** — the fear of observing a steep slope, that of which includes stairs; and
- > **Climacophobia** — the fear of climbing, or sometimes descending, stairs.

Score:

> The words are quite similar and they both rhyme, holding a total score of $25$ points.

Answer (score 0):

A hill name in New Zealand: 89 + 7 = 96 
http://bit.ly/1LryLZK

> Taumatawhakatangihangakoauauotamateaturipukakapikimaungahoronukupokaiwhenuakitanatahu
> Taumata

A village in Wales: 58+8=66
http://bit.ly/29HkOqr

> Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwyllllantysiliogogogoch
> LLanfair

Comment: These don't rhyme.

Comment: that name's longer than my thing..

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer!

> lanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwllllantysiliogogogoch and boondocks
> (They don’t perfectly rhyme but it’s close) 60